# flutter firebase firestore ui randomized

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 40,
    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
    childAspectRatio: 0.7,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    
    final blog = snapshot.docs[index].data();

    if (snapshot.hasMore &&
        index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
      snapshot.fetchMore();
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        context.toNamed(DetailScreen.routeName,
            arguments: blog);
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(blog.imageUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text(
            blog.topic,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
```

I'm paginating with the firebase_firestore_ui package, but I want the items in this list to be random. When I shuffle, I see the same elements. What can I do?I want the items in my list to come randomly.